# Change img src when navbar-shrink is active

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, if-statement, navbar

i'm using a bootstrap template where the navbar shrinks when scrolling down. I've made the navbar transparent until it scrolls, and it turns white simply by changing:

```
.navbar-default {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-default.navbar-shrink {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Now, my logo is mostly white because of the background-img but i want it to change to a black version when the navbar-shrink takes effect.

I tried to achieve it by changing the image src attr when the 'navbar-shrink' class is active with an if statement, but something must be wrong with it.

I've tried different ways and came up with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if($('nav').hasClass('navbar-shrink')) ({
    $('.pull-left img').attr('src', 'img/dolphin-nav2.svg');
  });
});
```

or this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if($('nav').attr('class', 'navbar-shrink')) ({
    $('.pull-left img').attr('src', 'img/dolphin-nav2.svg');
  });
});
```

but neither is working

Comment: I would use Css media queries for this

Comment: how?
it's not about resizing... the shrinking is basically the height changing by 10px or so when scrolling down

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood. I thought you were talking about when you shrink the window and the navbar collapses, disregard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add both images to your source code and show/hide the appropriate one based on the `navbar-shrink` class.

```
<div class="nav">
  <img class="white-image" ... />
  <img class="dark-image" ... />
</div>


.nav .white-image { display:none; }
.nav .dark-image  { display:block; }
.nav.navbar-shrink .white-image { display: block; }
.nav.navbar-shrink .dark-image  { display: none; }
```

Otherwise, you need to add your src changing logic to a scroll event, otherwise it is only called one time when the page loads.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
      if($('nav').attr('class', 'navbar-shrink')) {
        $('.pull-left img').attr('src', 'img/dolphin-nav2.svg');
      } else {
        ...
      }
    });
});
```

Note, you have erroneous parentheses surrounding your `if` statement brackets `{ }`

Comment: didn't even thought about display... way easier than js. Thanks a lot!